# Terminology trivia: Magento "module" or Magento "extension"? What's official?

Tags: magento-community

New to Magento I was wondering what word to use: "module" or "extension"?

Looking at Mage core code it seems the term "module" is used more by developers, perhaps partly to avoid confusion with "extension" in the sense of "file extension".

But non-programmers in the Magento world seem to favour "extension" over "module".

Is there an officially preferred term?
If not, should we have a Magento community referendum  :-)

What do you think?

Comment: Thanks for finding the earlier thread @fschmengler ... It doesn't really answer my question, although participants seem to agree that there isn't a single correct answer, yet... That was kind of my point... Should we or should we not standardise on a single word to avoid confusion? If so, what are the votes?

Comment: I was a participant and don't agree. The terms are not interchangable. But I fear I cannot back this up with an official statement yet.